# Why my numbers are not updating by themselves?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, calculator

So, I am using the [jquery-calx](https://github.com/xsanisty/jquery-calx) to calculate the price of some items. I have a different price depending on the base choise and the quantity. If the user chooses a 100 peaces of a full color base the price is different from 100 pieces of a One Side Monochromatic pattern. This is all working in my code, but there is a thing; If I choose One Side Monochromatic and them 100 pieces, the price in Total area is ok, but if I change the base to Full Color, for example, the price doesn't update. In this case, if I click again in the quantity the price does update. I would like to know if it is possible to make that update smoothly. Maybe create a button to update, I don't know. Would appreciate the help! Below Follows my code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="meishi" data-calx-identifier="CALX1452836013763">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-1 topic text-left">Base</label>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="design" data-cell="A1" value="10800">One Side Monochromatic
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="design" data-cell="B1" value="14040">One Side Color
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="design" data-cell="C1" value="16200">Full Color
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-2 text-right">
      <label data-cell="F1" data-formula="SUM(A1:C1)" data-format="$ 0,0"></label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-1 topic text-left">Quantity</label>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input class="maisuuA" type="radio" name="quantity" data-cell="A3" value="">100
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input class="maisuuB" type="radio" name="quantity" data-cell="B3" value="">200
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input class="maisuuC" type="radio" name="quantity" data-cell="C3" value="">300
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input class="maisuuD" type="radio" name="quantity" data-cell="D3" value="">400
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input class="maisuuE" type="radio" name="quantity" data-cell="E3" value="">500
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 text-right">
      <label data-cell="F3" data-formula="SUM(A3:E3)" data-format="$ 0,0"></label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-1 topic text-left">Total</label>
    <div class="col-lg-3 text-right col-lg-offset-8">
      <label data-cell="F6" data-format="$ 0,0" data-formula="SUM(F1:F5)">$ 0</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Script:

```
$('#meishi').calx();

$('input:radio[name="design"]').change(
  function() {
   if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == '10800') {
    $('.maisuuA').val('2160');
    $('.maisuuB').val('2484');
    $('.maisuuC').val('3132');
    $('.maisuuD').val('2808');
    $('.maisuuE').val('3456');
  } else if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == '14040') {
    $('.maisuuA').val('2808');
    $('.maisuuB').val('3132');
    $('.maisuuC').val('3780');
    $('.maisuuD').val('3456');
    $('.maisuuE').val('4104');
  } else if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == '16200') {
    $('.maisuuA').val('3240');
    $('.maisuuB').val('3564');
    $('.maisuuC').val('4212');
    $('.maisuuD').val('3888');
    $('.maisuuE').val('4536');
  }
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Put your code that handles changes and sets other fields to new values into a common function and then call that function each place that something changes.

Comment: if you change the value via script, you should call update method on calx, $('#meishi').calx('update')

Comment: and if you want to set value that impact calculation directly, use setValue method, $('#meishi').calx('setValue', 'A3', 3888);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used jquery-calx but it really isnt necessary for something like this. If it were me, I'd do it like this:

- store an array of values on the design inputs
- give all of the inputs a class of `update`
- when a any input is changed, get the array from the selected design input and the index of the selected "maisuu" input tells us which value to use from that stored array
- get the quantity from the value of the selected "maisuu"  elemet
- do your math and set the total

Like this:

***Note that you may need to tweak the math, not 100% sure the calculations are what you intended. Also, if you insist, I'm sure you could merge this technique with the use of jquery-calx**

#### [Here's a jsFiddle with comments explaining the code](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/y496hjL6/4/)

```js
$('.update').change(function() {
  var $design = $('input[name="design"]:checked');
  var $maisuu = $('input.maisuu:checked');
  var curMaisuu =$('.maisuu').index($maisuu);
  var maisuuArr =$.map($design.data('values').split(','), function(e, i) {
    return Number(e);
  });
  var base = $design.val() * 1000;   
  var upcharge = maisuuArr[curMaisuu] * 1000 
  var qty = $maisuu.val(); 
  var cost = ((base + upcharge)* qty ) / 1000
  if (base && qty) $('#total').text('$' + cost.toFixed(2))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" id="meishi" data-calx-identifier="CALX1452836013763">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-1 topic text-left">Base</label>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input class="update" type="radio" name="design" data-cell="A1" value="108.00" data-values="21.60,24.84,31.32,28.08,34.56">One Side Monochromatic
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input class="update" type="radio" name="design" data-cell="B1" value="140.40" data-values="28.08,31.32,37.80,34.56,41.04">One Side Color
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input class="update" type="radio" name="design" data-cell="C1" value="162.00" data-values="32.40,35.64,42.12,38.88,45.36">Full Color
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-2 text-right">
      <label data-cell="F1" data-formula="SUM(A1:C1)" data-format="$ 0,0"></label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-1 topic text-left">Quantity</label>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input class="maisuu update" type="radio" name="quantity" data-cell="A3" value="100">100
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input class="maisuu update" type="radio" name="quantity" data-cell="B3" value="200">200
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input class="maisuu update" type="radio" name="quantity" data-cell="C3" value="300">300
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input class="maisuu update" type="radio" name="quantity" data-cell="D3" value="400">400
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input class="maisuu update" type="radio" name="quantity" data-cell="E3" value="500">500
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 text-right">
      <label data-cell="F3" data-formula="SUM(A3:E3)" data-format="$ 0,0"></label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-1 topic text-left">Total</label>
    <div class="col-lg-3 text-right col-lg-offset-8">
      <label id="total">$ 0</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you, man! So far I've been using jquery without really studying the code. I'm just starting my studies. Thank you very much!

Comment: @FelipeFelixdeLuca after looking at it again this morning I realized it could still be a good bit simpler, I have updated my answer above and also included a link to a jsfiddle with comments explaining what is going on in the code

Comment: Sorry, man. I found a problem. The data-values are not been considered in the formula. For example, if the user chooses "One Side Monochromatic" and "100" the price should be 10800 + 2160, but the total price I'm getting is only 10800. I can't guess what is wrong, sorry.

Comment: @FelipeFelixdeLuca Sorry, I've fixed it above. I had the `e` and `i` backwards in the `$.map()`